# Can't delete row from SQLite database, yet no errors are issued

Tags: iphone, sqlite, delete-row

I am using what, according to my Xcode debugger, is proper syntax to delete a row from a table in my project. However, when I go back to check my database, it still exists. My other SQL syntax for inserting entries is correct, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. NSLogs confirm both variables are being sent correctly:

```
    -(void) deleteSelectedRowFromTable: (NSString *) tableName cityName:(NSString *)city 
{

[self openDB];
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE city LIKE %@", tableName, city];
const char *sql = [sqlStr UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(db);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this statement

NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM '%@' WHERE city LIKE '%@%%'", tableName, city];

Comment: I tried your code, and it gave me this error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: failed to prepare statement with message 'not an error'.'

Comment: This works, along with changing the line to: if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK)

Answer (score 1):

Check that the operand to LIKE is a string (should have quotation marks around it).  I've never used XCode, but if you change your 5th line to read:

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE city LIKE '%@'", tableName, city];
```

Does that work?

Comment: that produces two errors: NSInternalInconsistencyException and an Assertion Failure. I tried that route...it's funny, using quotes works in my GUI editor when I run the query, but crashes my app in Xcode.

Comment: @squeezemylime Note that you're failing an assert if the result of `sqlite_prepare_v2()` **is** `SQLITE_OK`, when what you meant is if it **isn't**.

Answer (score 0):

you have just prepared the statement, you should step that statement.

```
-(void) deleteSelectedRowFromTable: (NSString *) tableName cityName:(NSString *)city 
{

[self openDB];
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE city LIKE %@", tableName, city];
const char *sql = [sqlStr UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
      /**this one will execute when there is error in your query**/
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
else
{
     /************just add this one****************/
     sqlite3_step(statement);
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(db);

}
```

i hope this one will help you.

Comment: thanks! I am trying this, although when I get to this line:   NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
 it comes up with an error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: failed to prepare statement with message 'near ",": syntax error'.'